# How to stop TextWrangler changing the text file icon?

Tags: filesystem, text-editor, bbedit

I use a several text editors, but every time I save with TextWrangler it changes the file's icon in Finder to a TextWrangler icon with the following extended attributes;

> com.apple.FinderInfo
>   com.apple.TextEncoding

How do I get TextWrangler to stop doing this? I can't find a settings that seems to fix this.

Comment: Have you [contacted Bare Bones Software](http://barebones.com/contact/technical.html) about this behaviour? Bare Bones make TextWangler and are best placed to help.

Comment: @GrahamMiln. Thanks for the tip, they responded very quickly; see the answer below for the detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A support request was filed and Bare Bones responded quickly.

TextWrangler sets the file type (com.apple.FinderInfo; file icon) when it determines that the file name cannot be used to determine that it is a text file. The exact determination here is not too important; as I found, hence I would assume that source code files would fall into this category. The text encoding is a standard attribute and is set to indicate the file's character encoding.

To disable the writing of these extended file attributes, the following command is used;

```
defaults write com.barebones.textwrangler WriteExtendedAttributes -string "Never"
```

The command itself is documented in the TextWrangler help files; but not how it relates to the character encoding and file associations.

To find and clear the attributes of the modified file(s), you can use the following standard commands;

```
ls -@l # list the files with extended attributes
xattr -c filename.sh # where the file name and extension is as required
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is because TextWrangler sets the "Always Open With" option in your case. I can suggest you to take a look for an option to stop this or to try manually make a file to Always Open With TextEdit (for example) just to test if this is the issue.

Comment: I'm afraid not, TextWrangler doesn't change the "Always Open With". I've set and reset those several times, it makes no difference to the file icon in Finder.

Comment: Than I can suggest to completely remove TextWrangler, clear cache and then install it again. 

You may use AppCleaner (http://www.freemacsoft.net/appcleaner) in order to find all additional files of the App and remove them. Then use CCleaner (https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) to remove all cache of your Mac.

Comment: Could you please expand on how reinstalling TextWrangler would correct it adding extended attributes to the files it saves?